# Is this proof of divergence correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the sequence $a_n= (-1)^n$. Let us show that it does not converge to any $L\in\mathbb{R}$.

*Proof:* Let us suppose for a contradiction that $a_n$ converges to some $L\in\mathbb{R}$. Then for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N$ such that when $n>N$, $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$.
So let us look at when $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. Then there must exist $N$ such that $n>N \implies |a_n-L| < \frac{1}{2}$.

We know that $|a_{n+1} - a_n|=|(-1)^{n+1} - (-1)^{n}|=2$ for all $n$.

Thus we can write $$2=|a_{n+1} - a_n|= |(a_{n+1} - L) - (a_n -L)| \leq|(a_{n+1} - L)| + |(a_n -L)|<1.$$

This is clearly a contradiction. Hence the sequence $a_n$ does not converge to any $L\in\mathbb{R}$.
$$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$$
I would like to verify whether or not this proof is correct.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: Well done. I spent some time trying to find something to criticize for the sake of pedagogy ( who will believe that) but to no avail.